# how to get data from nested json file for d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

How to get lat, lon, date?
I have used nested but it's not working. lat and lon are showing data in HTML console but unable to use lat and lon to display location as circles in the map.

the issue is in the var nested part. I have tried multiple ways to solve but unable to.

here is the data:

```
[{
    "session":{"id":"1"},
    "location":{"lat":36.958992,"lon":-122.045301},
    "number":{"created":{"date":"2018-05-19 00:00:51.000000"}},

    "session":{"id":"2"},
    "location":{"lat":40.958992,"lon":-100.045301},
    "number":{"created":{"date":"2018-05-29 00:00:11.000000"}}
}]
```

here is the code I have used:
it is html file with everything;

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
path {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 0.25px;
  fill: grey;
}
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v0.min.js"></script>
<script>
var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .center([0, 5 ])
    .scale(200)
    .rotate([-180,0]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var g = svg.append("g");

function process(d){
    var processed = {
        lat: parseFloat(d.location.lat),
        lon: parseFloat(d.location.lon),
    }
    return processed;
}    

// load and display the World
d3.json("world-110m2.json", function(error, topology) {

// load and display the cities
d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {

    console.log("data", data);

var nest_data = data.map(process);
    console.log("nest_data", nest_data);

var nested = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) { return d.location; })
.rollup(function(leaves) { return leaves.length; })
.entries(data);

    console.log("nested", nested);

    g.selectAll("circle")
       .data(data)
       .enter()
       .append("circle")
       .attr("cx", function(d) {
               return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];
       })
       .attr("cy", function(d) {
               return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];
       })
       .attr("r", 5)
       .style("fill", "red");
});

g.selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.countries)
          .geometries)
    .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
});

// zoom and pan
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .on("zoom",function() {
        g.attr("transform","translate("+ 
            d3.event.translate.join(",")+")scale("+d3.event.scale+")");
        g.selectAll("circle")
            .attr("d", path.projection(projection));
        g.selectAll("path")  
            .attr("d", path.projection(projection)); 

  });

svg.call(zoom)

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want to use `nest_data`, then do `data(nest_data)`.

Comment: i did but it does not work. .. i also used d.location.lon but it only shows one value .....not multiple locations    thank you